# How do I migrate product fields?

Tags: drush, migrations, 9

I'm migrating Drupal 7 commerce products to Drupal 9 and I'm using:

- Drush (10.5.0)
- migrate_plus
- migrate_tools
- commerce_migrate_commerce
- commerce_migrate

I have successfully migrated nodes, but I cannot migrate fields. In other words, I have node titles and bodies, but not all the additional fields I have on Drupal 7.

I used the following migration IDs.

- d7_file
- d7_user
- d7_node_complete:general_product
- d7_node:general_product (What's the difference between this and the previous one?)
- commerce1_product_variation:product
- commerce1_product:general_product
- d7_field
- d7_field_instance
- d7_field_instance_widget_settings

What am I missing? Where should I dig?